# Rust for loop with BigUint

Tags: rust

I am new to rust and trying to write a for loop with BigUint:

```
use num_bigint::BigUint;

fn loop(k: &[u8]) -> BigUint {
    let mut k = BigUint::from_bytes_le(k);

    while k != BigUint::zero() {
        k >>= 1;
    }

    k
}
```

But when I try to compile i get the error:

```
no function or associated item named `zero` found for struct `num_bigint::BigUint` in the current scope
function or associated item not found in `num_bigint::BigUint`
help: items from traits can only be used if the trait is in scoperustc(E0599)
lib.rs(53, 25): function or associated item not found in `num_bigint::BigUint`
```

My Cargo.toml file has the following dependency:

```
[dependencies]
num-bigint = { version = "0.2.2" }
```

Am I missing some import? How can I use `BigUint::zero()` ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As the error suggests, "*items from traits can only be used if the trait is in scope*".  The `zero` method is defined by the [`num_traits::Zero`](https://docs.rs/num-traits/0.2.14/num_traits/identities/trait.Zero.html) trait.  Therefore, import it (you will need to add the `num-traits` dependency to your `Cargo.toml` too):

```
[dependencies]
num-bigint = "0.2.2"
num-traits = "0.2.14"
```

```rust
use num_traits::Zero;
```

Comment: Thanks, do I need to this for every method/(trait?) associated with BigUint? I wanted to also use is_odd for BigUint and then I need to add the ```num_integer::Integer``` trait and ```num-integer``` dependency?